# Having troubles getting returned value from an async/await function on ES6, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am attempting to subtract an `id` from an array to use it a parameter but I am having some issues on the try.

This is the code:

```
  const takeId = async (): Promise<any> => {
    const newArr = await departmentResolution[0].template;

    getTemplateId = await newArr.map((item: any) => {
      return item;
    });

    return getTemplateId[0]; // this returns { id: 11, anotherKey: 'value' }
  }

 const setId = async () => {
    const el = await takeId();

    return el.id;
  }
```

If `console.log(setId())` I get *`Promise`* and all I need is the value returned by it to use here:

```
      <Container>
        <Breadcrumb />
        {handleTemplate(setId())}
      </Container>
```

Comment: Please go read about how `await` works.  It ONLY does something useful when the value you `await` is a promise.  This code looks very misguided as there don't appear to be any actual asynchronous operations that generate promises and therefore no reason to use `async` or `await`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I read already but still not getting this concept. I am just asking for help to get a clearer idea. I don't think `Please go read` is a proper answer for a site where people come to ask questions about their doubts.

Comment: What is `departmentResolution[0].template`?

Comment: Hi, @Nick `.template` is the array of objects that contains the `id` key I need.

Comment: I see. So it seems like you have no Promises that you actually need to await. There's nothing asynchronous going on. You could remove all `async` and `await` keywords in your code and it would work fine. You would also need to fix the type of your return value from `takeId` (it's just an object).

Comment: Using `await` for sychronous methods make no sense, This keywork is used to wait for an asychronous methods like `fetch` which takes time to complete and return a value, Acutally your code should work fine after removing all `async` & `await` keywords, But if you are trying to practice them, i suggest doing it with `fetch` method

Comment: Well, I said that because you're completely misusing `await` which shows you don't have a basic level of understanding of what it should be used for and how to use it and writing long tutorials on that type of broad subject is not what stackoverflow is for.  Then, to add to the problem, you don't even really explain what problem you're trying to solve.  To start with, you should remove all use of `async`, `await` and `promises` from this code since none of the conditions under which they would be useful appear to be present.

Comment: I've now made a couple suggestions.  If you're going to be offended by them, I and others will go away.  You wrote a very unclear question.  I responded with some advice (that probably inappropriately showed a little frustration), but the advice is legit.  I will take your suggestion and make no further attempts to advise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the async method in your render template.

In the template, use a state variable which you update when the promise resolves. When a state value is used, once the state is updated, it triggers as a re-render

```js
state = {
  someKey: 'someInitialValue'
};

async myMethod() {
  const myAsyncValue = await anotherAsyncMethod();
  this.setState({ someKey: myAsyncValue });
}

render() {
  return <div>{this.state.someKey}</div>;
}
```